# Can someone explain what the "padding" In keras is used for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras

I'm writing a neural network code and I have to use Conv2D but I don't understand what for the parameter padding is used for!

```
X = Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation ="relu",padding="same"(input)
```

Comment: see padding argument in https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/

Answer (score 0):

Same padding means the size of output feature-maps are the same as the input feature-maps (under the assumption of stride=1).
As mentioned in comments check [https://keras.io/layers/convolutional](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

The `padding` parameter is used to control how much padding is added to the input. When performing the convolution operation the spatial dimensions of the output are slightly smaller than the input, as the filter kernel can only be slid in the image without going out of bounds.

If you set `padding='same'` then Keras will compute and add the required padding to the input image so the spatial size of the output is the same as the input.

If you set `padding='valid'` (the default), then no padding is added and the output is smaller than the input.